# How to erase the straight gray line in the Visual Studio Code editor?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I am using the Visual Studio Code editor, however, there are always straight gray lines appears for the code block as the following:

[image]

May I ask how to erase the lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
It is to disable the "**editor.renderIndentGuides**" function as the following:

```
"editor.renderIndentGuides": true,
```

Comment: Is there any extension for the lines? For example, when I click on the line which has the bracket, Visual Studio Code will show the line to the corresponding bracket.

Answer (score 1):

Tools/Options/Text Editor/General/
display/ UNCHECK "Show structure guide lines"

Comment: This is a vscode question.  Not Visual Studio.